# Is it a bad practice to reinit stylesheets?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to achieve that the UI updates whenever the dark mode is toggled from the control centre. I've been searching for practices for hours on end, without success..

I came up with the following solution: instead of static stylesheets, I give them back by functions. **Is this a bad practice?**

Does this have any performance issues?

I have a lot of styles.

```
import React, {useState, useMemo, useRef} from 'react';

import {BaseStyle} from '../../styles';

import {ThemeContext} from '../Contexts/ThemeContext';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const theme = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles(theme).container}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = (theme) => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...BaseStyle.container(theme),
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  // lot more...
});
```

**styles.js** (BaseStyle)

```
export const container = (theme) => StyleSheet.create({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor: theme === 'dark' ? Colors.DARK : Colors.WHITE,
});

// ... lot more
```

---

**Edit**

I came up with an other example (which might be better:)

```
import React, {useState, useMemo, useRef} from 'react';

import {baseStyle} from '../../styles';

import {ThemeContext} from '../Contexts/ThemeContext';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const theme = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles(theme).container}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = (theme) => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...baseStyle(theme).container,
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  // lot more...
});
```

**styles.js** (baseStyle)

```
export const baseStyle = theme =>
    StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: theme === 'dark' ? Colors.DARK : Colors.WHITE,
        },
        // ... lot more
    });

export default baseStyle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your ThemeContext should return the theme name and the colors that each theme would use

```js
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';

const Colors = {
  dark: {
    background: 'black',
    text: 'white',
    switchColor: '#c4caf5',
  },
  light: {
    background: 'white',
    text: 'black',
    switchColor: '#4503fc',
    switchBgColor: '#9c78ff',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext({});

const getTheme = (isDark) => {
  return {
    theme: isDark ? 'dark' : 'light',
    colors: isDark ? Colors.dark : Colors.light,
  };
};
export default function useTheme(isDark) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(getTheme(isDark));
  const changeTheme = (bool) => {
    setTheme(getTheme(bool));
  };
  return [theme, changeTheme];
}
```

Now you can refractor your code to not need styles to be a function:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {theme, colors} = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  // if you are going to be using the theme base style alot in a component
  // then you can store it as a variable and pass it along to other components
  const themeStyle = {backgroundColor:colors.background}
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container,themeStyle]>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

A [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/bj-uYxfdi)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the example! Yes, this is a good option, but this way I'd have to separate the styles into a different file/variable. Do you think performance wise it is bad  to give back the stylesheets by functions? That way I could keep all the styles in one file